# How to do FULL OUTER JOIN with three tables in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

Consider the following tables:

```sql
create table `t1` (
  `date` date,
  `value` int
);

create table `t2` (
  `date` date,
  `value` int
);

create table `t3` (
  `date` date,
  `value` int
);

insert into `t1` (`date`, `value`)
values ("2022-01-01", 1),
       ("2022-03-01", 3),
       ("2022-04-01", 4);
       
insert into `t2` (`date`, `value`)
values ("2022-01-01", 1),
       ("2022-02-01", 2),
       ("2022-04-01", 4);

insert into `t3` (`date`, `value`)
values ("2022-01-01", 1),
       ("2022-02-01", 2),
       ("2022-03-01", 3);
```

The `t1` table is missing `2022-02-01` date and `t2` is missing `2022-03-01` and `t3` is missing `2022-04-01`. I want to join these three tables so that it produces the following result:

```
| t1.date    | t1.value | t2.date    | t2.value | t3.date    | t3.value | 
|            |          |            |          |            |          |
| 2022-01-01 | 1        | 2022-01-01 | 1        | 2022-01-01 | 1        |
| null       | null     | 2022-02-01 | 2        | 2022-02-01 | 2        |
| 2022-03-01 | 3        | null       | null     | 2022-03-01 | 3        |
| 2022-04-01 | 4        | 2022-04-01 | 4        | null       | null     |
```

I know how to do `full outer join` with two tables but with three or more tables things are more complicated. I've tried queries like this but it didn't produce the result I want:

```sql
select *
from `t1`
left join `t2` on `t2`.`date` = `t1`.`date`
left join `t3` on `t3`.`date` = `t2`.`date` or `t3`.`date` = `t1`.`date`

union

select *
from `t1`
right join `t2` on `t2`.`date` = `t1`.`date`
right join `t3` on `t3`.`date` = `t2`.`date` or `t3`.`date` = `t1`.`date`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track but you have to consider all combinations - 3 tables - 4 union clauses.

```
-- t1 full join with t2
select *
from `t1`
left join `t2` on `t2`.`date` = `t1`.`date` 
union 
select *
from `t1`
right join `t2` on `t2`.`date` = `t1`.`date` 

-- t1 full join with t3
union 
select *
from `t1`
left join `t3` on `t3`.`date` = `t1`.`date` 

union 
select *
from `t1`
right join `t3` on `t3`.`date` = `t1`.`date`
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The full join of t1 with t2 and t1 with t3 returns the correct result but when I union them together (the 2nd union) it duplicates some columns and I'm not sure how to fix it. Maybe I have to `left join` the result of the first part with the second part instead of `union`

Comment: I dont know your data and uniqueness - please make sure you join on unique keys or on whatever youre trying to have full outer join.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to do; the left join is used to keep all the rows from your left table and bring all the matching rows from your right table.

It means: since you do not have the '2022-02-01' date in the t1 it will never appear in your query by using a left join.

Now if you want to combine all the results from three tables, a union between the three tables will do the trick:

select *
from t1
union
select *
from t2
union
select *
from t3;

If you want it ordered just make a subquery:

select *
from (
select *
from t1
union
select *
from t2
union
select *
from t3
) as allData
order by `date`;

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My use-case is a little hard to explain. Basically I want to have the `value` column of `t1`, `t2` and `t3` in a single row but I don't want the rows that do not have a value for a specific date to be excluded from the final result. The query you wrote returns completely a different result.

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
select a.`date`,a.value,a2.`date`,a2.value,a3.`date`,a3.value
from  date_range b left join `t1` a 
on  a.`date`=b.dates
left join `t2` a2
on a2.`date`=b.dates
left join `t3` a3
on a3.`date`=b.dates;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fbc85/9

This is only concerned for these three tables only..
You also would need to create a date range table for all the ranges presenting in the dates present in all the tables!!!

Comment: Thank you for the response. The query is a little hard to read but I tried it and it didn't return the result I want. I think there should be a `right join` somewhere. You cannot do it with just `left join`

Comment: @Arman check the fiddle for output results!!! ITs showing the correct results!!

Comment: Nope, `2022-03-01` and `2022-04-01` are duplicated in the result. It should have 6 columns (2 for each table) but it only has 4.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the result I wanted with a different approach:

```sql
select 
  t1.date,
  t1.value,
  t2.date,
  t2.value,
  t3.date,
  t3.value
from (
  select t1.date from t1
  union
  select t2.date from t2
  union
  select t3.date from t3
) t
left join t1 on t1.date = t.date
left join t2 on t2.date = t.date
left join t3 on t3.date = t.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do (t1 full join t2) full join t3 with a full join implementation of choice. Provided joining on primary keys so duplicates must be excluded

```
with t12 as (
    select coalesce(t2.`date`, t1.`date`) 'date', t1.`date` t1date, t1.`value` t1val ,t2.`date` t2date, t2.`value` t2val
    from t1
    left join t2 on t2.`date` = t1.`date` 
    union
    select coalesce(t2.`date`, t1.`date`) 'date', t1.`date` t1date, t1.`value` t1val ,t2.`date` t2date, t2.`value` t2val
    from t1
    right join t2 on t2.`date` = t1.`date`     
)
select coalesce(t12.`date`, t3.`date` ) d, t1date, t1val ,t2date, t2val, t3.`date` t3date, t3.`value` t3val 
from t12
left join t3 on t12.`date` = t3.`date` 
union
select coalesce(t12.`date`, t3.`date` ) d, t1date, t1val ,t2date, t2val, t3.`date` t3date, t3.`value` t3val 
from t12
right join t3 on t12.`date` = t3.`date` 
order by d
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RR_fb3LQ)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to UNION ALL dates from all three tables. Then you sort and distinct this union, and finally you left join all three tables consequently.

In your last solution I am still missing DISTINCT and ORDER BY.

This should do the result you wanted:

```
Select * From
(
Select distinct `date` From (
Select distinct `date` From t1
Union All
Select distinct `date` From t2
Union All
Select distinct `date` From t3 ) f
Order By f.`date`
) a
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.`date` = a.`date`
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.`date` = a.`date`
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.`date` = a.`date`
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
select 
t1.date as t1_date,t1.value as t1_value ,
t2.date as t2_date ,t2.value as t2_value,
t3.date as t3_date ,t3.value as t3_value 
from t1 
full outer join t2 on t1.date  = t2.date
left join t3 on t1.date  = t3.date or t2.date  = t3.date ;
```